# Working and saving histogram of data

Tags: r, geotiff-tiff, ggplot2, histogram

I'm new to R and struggling to create a histogram and add a mean line. I've tried both hist() and doing it through ggplot, but keep seeing errors.
I'm using the newest version of R studio on a windows computer.
The code:

```
transformRasterToMappableDF <- function(raster) {
  test_spdf <- as(raster, "SpatialPixelsDataFrame")
  test_df <- as.data.frame(test_spdf)
  colnames(test_df) <- c("value", "x", "y")
  return(test_df)
}
customColors <- c("#E66100", "#FFFFFF", "#5D3A9B")
setwd(path.out.specific)
combined <- raster(paste0(spname, "_COMBINED_local_final_ensemble_raster_local.tif"))
current <- raster(paste0(spname, "_current_local_final_ensemble_raster_local.tif"))
combined1 <- (combined - minValue(combined))* 1/(maxValue(combined) - minValue(combined))
current1 <- (current - minValue(current))* 1/(maxValue(current) - minValue(current))

range_shift <- (combined1 - current1)
plot(combined1,
     main="Range shift",
     axes=FALSE)
png((paste0(spname, "_future_proj.png"))) #not sure if this is right
plot(current1,
     main="Range shift",
     axes=FALSE)
png((paste0(spname, "_current_proj.png"))) #not sure if this is right

difference <- ggplot() +
  geom_tile(data=transformRasterToMappableDF(range_shift), aes(x=x, y=y, fill=value)) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours = customColors) 
difference
plot(difference)
setwd(path.out.specific)
png((paste0(spname, "_range_shift.png"))) #not sure if this is right
plot(difference)

mean <- calc(range_shift, fun = sd, na.m = T)
test <- hist(range_shift,
     main = "Range Shift of species",
     xlab = "Growth Shift", ylab = "Frequency",
     col = "blue", breaks = 5)
```

After the histogram, I want to add a vertical line to indicate where the mean and standard deviations are. I've tried using abline

```
abline(v = mean(range_shift, na.rm = T), col = "red", lwd = 2)
```

but get the error "Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) :
no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector"

I want to save these images as .png, but with this current code it's showing up as blank in the saved folder. I also have gotten the warning
Warning: Raster objects have different extents. Result for their intersection is returned with the data before the histogram is plotted.

Much appreciation for any help you can give!

Comment: `calc(range_shift, fun = sd, na.m = T)` has `na.m` which should be `na.rm`, and you should spell out `na.rm=TRUE` instead of using `T`. These aren't the cause of the error though.

Answer (score 1):

You should always try and shrink your problem down to the minimum amount of code needed. And also read and think about the error message.

Your `range_shift` is a raster, so is your raster special or does it happen with any raster? Let's try a tiny test:

```
> r = raster(matrix(1:12,3,4))
> hist(r)
> abline(v=mean(r))
Error in int_abline(a = a, b = b, h = h, v = v, untf = untf, ...) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector
```

Okay, that's your error in 3 lines instead of 30. Now why can't it add a line at the mean of `r`? What is `mean(r)`?

```
> mean(r)
class      : RasterLayer 
dimensions : 3, 4, 12  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : NA 
source     : memory
names      : layer 
values     : 1, 12  (min, max)
```

Ah, its a raster. `mean(r)` takes pixel means for stacks of rasters, or the simple raster itself if there's only one layer in the stack. If you want the mean of the values themselves, you have to get the values:

```
> abline(v=mean(values(r)))
>
```

Add `na.rm=TRUE` etc as needed.